# SRA toolkit for Ubuntu 20.04 TLS

Tags: 20.04

I'm trying to install SRA toolkit on my Ubuntu 20.04 TLS with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install sra-toolkit
```

I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package sra-toolkit is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'sra-toolkit' has no installation candidate
```

I had installed this package with the same command on Ubuntu 18.04, but now it doesn't work. Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: There is no `sra-toolkit` in `focal` repos.

Comment: Thank you so much. If I go back to 18.04 will the problem be resolved?

Comment: Yes, the package is available in the 18.04 repos. But you can install to 20.04 from source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sra-toolkit` is not available in 20.04 LTS (*focal*), but you can install it manually by using [packages from 19.10 (*eoan*)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/sra-toolkit):

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/ncbi-vdb/libncbi-vdb2_2.9.3+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/ncbi-vdb/libncbi-wvdb2_2.9.3+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/sra-sdk/sra-toolkit_2.9.3+dfsg-1build2_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libncbi-vdb2_2.9.3+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libncbi-wvdb2_2.9.3+dfsg-2_amd64.deb

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-sra-libs
Package: libncbi-vdb2
Pin: version 2.9.3+dfsg-2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libncbi-wvdb2
Pin: version 2.9.3+dfsg-2
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF

sudo apt-get install ./sra-toolkit_2.9.3+dfsg-1build2_amd64.deb
```